# What is the difference between Java Servlet Filters and Jetty Filters?

Tags: java, jetty, servlet-filters

What is the difference between Java Servlet Filters and Jetty QoS Filter & DoS filter?

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty QoS Filter and DoS Filter are Java Servlet Filters.

The only thing is that they are aware of and use internal Jetty features to do what they need to do. (namely some manipulation of the low level network behavior at the Jetty internal EndPoint)